# Lat and Long sorting Cast decimal

Tags: t-sql, decimal, latitude-longitude

I am trying to figure out why I am unable to return a longitude field by order descending.

When I use the following leaves some records out of order? It isnt picking up the max value.

select cast(LONGITUDE as decimal(12,8)) from long
order by LONGITUDE desc

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtp1M.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but I'd try

```
Order By 1 desc
```

So ordered them by the casted value not the uncasted one.